# Parts to replace when changing transmission

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, manual-transmission

For a simple manual front wheel drive car like a 04 Honda Civic, or any Honda Civic, what parts should be replaced that are easier to replace when the transmission is out? I'm replacing a manual transmission and I am replacing the rear main seal of the engine, input shaft bearing, clutch kit, and flywheel. Also the slave cylinder, just for s****.

Also relating to transmissions, are there any automatic transmission specific parts to replace when replacing the transmission? Thanks.

Comment: Other than a throwout bearing, I think you have it covered.

Comment: Also if worn.. replace the spigot bush/bearing.

Comment: You say you are dealing with a manual transmission , but you then change to automatic - which is it? As they are different.

Comment: @orb what is a spigot bushing? Nm googled it

Answer (score 1):

The few car designs I know all use an engine carrier frame. That frame needs to be removed when removing the transmission (major work). So you could replace the silent-blocks, if present, that hold the frame to the unibody. Should the swaybar bushings be only accessible with the carrier frame removed, it would be also a good opportunity to replace them